# Get clicked ng-repeat item in parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code right now:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.slides = [{
            title: "Slide 1"
        },{
            title: "Slide 2"
        }];
        $scope.clicked = {title: "undefined slide"};
});

app.directive("scroller", function() {
  return {
    template: "<div slide ng-click='click()' ng-repeat='slide in slides'></div>"
  };
});

app.directive("slide", function() {
  return {
    template: "{{slide.title}}",
    controller: function($scope) {
        // controller
        $scope.click = function() {
            // Tell parent I was clicked
        }
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // link
    }
  };
});
```

I want the `clicked` in the main controller to be the `slide` which was clicked.

---

```
$scope.clicked = $scope.slide
```

obviously does not work because of the repeat scope.

---

Two way databinding does not work, because this would create a seconde scope for the element and hence the template of the `slide` directive would stop working.

---

I know that

```
$scope.$parent.clicked = $scope.slide;
```

would work, but I wanted to ask for a better solution, because I don't like accessing the parent scope like this.

Can someone please help me with this? Maybe broadcast the clicked item?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'require' option of the directive. This option is used to specify that your controller requires another one to work properly.

Your code should look like this:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.slides = [{
            title: "Slide 1"
        },{
            title: "Slide 2"
        }];
        $scope.clicked = {title: "undefined slide"};

        this.slideClicked = function(slide){
            $scope.clicked = slide;
        };
});

app.directive("scroller", function() {
  return {
    template: "<div>{{clicked.title}}</div><div slide ng-click='click(slide)' ng-repeat='slide in slides'></div>",
    controller: 'ctrl'
  };
});

app.directive("slide", function() {
  return {
    template: "{{slide.title}}",
    require: '^scroller',
    controller: function($scope) {
        // controller
        $scope.click = function(slide) {
            $scope.containerController.slideClicked(slide);
        }
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        scope.containerController = controllers;        

        // link
    }
  };
});
```

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/60zbpvau/1/

Comment: Ok, so I would have to move the click handler to the link function, right?

Comment: Well, you don't have to move it there. You can store reference on parent controller in your slide controller's scope or even add it to the child controller itself (to do this you need to specify array of required controllers. They will be provided to your link function as an array. Then you'll have access both to slide and ctrl controllers in the link function and bind them as you wish).

Comment: I understand what you did, but for some reason I get a "No controller" exception or just no output depending on if I use `restrict` in the scroller directive.

Comment: My fault. 'require' option must be added into the slide controller. Fixed code. Also this link might be helpful: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/directive-to-directive-communication

Comment: Well I moved it but am still getting the exception.

Comment: This approach is too convoluted, tightly coupled and the part of assigning the consumer consumer controller to the scope and using it looks equally bad, IMHO. Makes is less reusable as well. There is a strong coupling between the directive and its consumer's consumer controller. In order to share the behavior is what function bindings are created for.

Comment: Agree with PSL. Direct interaction between controllers is not a kind of 'best practice' in angular. But in some cases it's acceptable (when child directive can't be used outside of parent's directive. wizard and wizard's page for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the information in a property of a property of `$scope`. When the `$scope` is created for the child controls, its properties are shallow copied.